# Unreadable characters in command section and Quickfix window

Tags: encoding, plugin-fugitive

Good day!

Do yo have any idea how to fix this issue? Please refer to the screenshot.
[image]

I don't have the slightest clue why these characters are appearing. My vim-fugitive plugin was working fine before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your terminal? Have you tried it in another one, say, Konsole, Gnome terminal, Xterm or Alacritty? GVim?

Comment: Font issue most likely. Or encoding maybe

Comment: Looks like the symbol some apps show when a font doesn't have a representation for a particular Unicode character. The number in the box is the code point, I think.

Comment: The character in the box is 001B, which is ESC. These are terminal escape sequences: `ESC [ >4;2m` (the `>` is somewhat unusual here, `ESC [ n m` for a number `n` or sequence of numbers separated by semicolon is to set colors and attributes IIRC.)

Comment: Where's the the `[`? Do you think that's it overlapping with the 001B glyph? Without the `[` it's not color codes. Either it signals beginning of ansi mode or it's "set numeric keypad mode" from what I can tell. Even with `[` I don't think it is color. 1B 5B 3E is ... "set current keyboard language"? ... hmm.

Comment: My eyes glazed over reading an old terminal sequence manual so I welcome someone else to look. :D

Comment: @MaximKim I am using i3-sensible-terminal. The default which comes out of the box for i3. No, I haven't tried it with other terminals.

Comment: @Oneb i3-sensible-terminal is just a wrapper to run a terminal program... I'm guessing you have something like urxvt or similar... Maybe use `ps` to figure it out? What is `$TERM` set to (in the shell)?

Comment: @BLayer Yeah the `[` is superposed, if you look closely at the right side of the square around the Unicode for ESC you'll see the `[` there... These are almost surely terminal escape sequences, but the `>` looks unusual there, might be what is causing the issue...

Comment: @filbranden Since learning that the code point is 001B I've been 99% sure it's ANSI escape sequences and if there's really a `[` in there, which seems to be the case, a CSI sequence, in particular. I've just questioned whether they are color-related. It depends on whether the `>` is an error or not. If not, then I think it has to be a non-color control sequence. Knowing for sure about the `>` would be nice but it might be more productive to attack this from a different angle. (Like trying a different terminal, for one.)

Comment: Good day! I'll try to use a different terminal and keep you guys posted asap. Just been busy for past couple of days.

Comment: Some interesting parallels between this one and [VIM mouse scrolling on Konsole show ^\[OA at the top and ^\[OB at the bottom of the page](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/27015)  ?

Comment: Another sighting [What's t\_TE and t\_TI added by vim 8?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/27399) (confirmed by author as same issue).

Comment: As advised in `:h modifyOtherKeys`, simply `:let &t_TE='' | let &t_TI=''` should help.