# gvim on ubuntu breaks the console when calling system command in vimrc

Tags: vimrc, console

I use this version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12 kompiliert am Aug 29 2020 14:11:37)
Inklusive der Patches: 1-1539
Verändert von jonathon.fernyhough@york.ac.uk
Übersetzt von jonathon.fernyhough@york.ac.uk
```

under Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Since a couple of days, my console get's garbled with strange chars like this:

```
wolfgang@cato:~$ gvim
[>4;m[>4;2mwolfgang@cato:~$
```

If I use the internal gvim console (:shell) it's pretty useless, since everything I type in is broken with strange char sequences.

I tried to track down the problem. It does not occur with an empty .vimrc. What I found out was that if my .vimrc contains only one single line:

```
let hostname = substitute(system('hostname'), '\n', '', '')
```

, this seems to be enough to cause the effect. If I change this to the (useless) line

```
let hostname = substitute('cato', '\n', '', '')
```

the effect is gone. So I guess it has something to do with the `system()` call.

Any idea what could cause this behaviour and how it might get fixed?

Comment: Looks like Vim enables the modifyOtherKeys feature, while your terminal doesn't support it.  Your `TERM` might be misconfigured.  Try to add this in your vimrc: `let [&t_TI, &t_TE] = ['', '']`.  Or fix your `TERM`.

Comment: *If I use the internal gvim console (:shell) it's pretty useless, since everything I type in is broken with strange char sequences.* Add the `!` flag in `'guioptions'`; like this `set guioptions+=!`.

Comment: This one is similar: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26961/18609

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @user938271: using let [&t_TI, &t_TE] = ['', ''] reduced the number of printed sequences. My TERM says `xterm-256color` for a gnome terminal. If I start from a real xterm, everything is fine. Also, `export TERM=` fixes the problem in a gnome terminal.

Comment: @user938271: `set guioptions+=!` also fixed the garbled internal console, thank you very much!